# How to prove a regression analytically while having a complicated integral?

Tags: integration, regression, error-function

Here I have an integral derived from a heat conduction problem

$$f(r)=r*\int_0^H \frac{e^{-(r^2+h^2)} \ \ \ \ +  \frac{erfc(\sqrt{\ r^2+h^2} \  \ \ )}{ \sqrt{\ r^2+h^2}}}{r^2+h^2}dh$$
I solved this one numerically and found out a regression like $f(r)=\frac{a}{r}+b$ for $H>>r$, where $a$ and $b$ are functions of $r$ and $H$. I tried to reach an analytical expression for $a$ and $b$, but can't solve the integral properly.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you use $$ it will be somewhat larger.

Comment: I cannot understand what regression you are talking about. What are the parameter(s) to be adjusted in order to fit the function to what kind of data?

Comment: I was comparing numerical result of $f(r)$ to an arbitrary function $g(r)=a/r+b$. I wonder if it's possible to have an expression for a and b without using numerical data.

Comment: If I properly understand, you have tables $(r_i, H_i, f_i)$. Would it be possible for you to show at least part of the table ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^H \frac{e^{-(r^2+h^2)} +  \frac{\operatorname{erfc}\sqrt{\ r^2+h^2}}{ \sqrt{\ r^2+h^2}}}{r^2+h^2}dh \,\stackrel{u=r^2+h^2}{=} \,\int_{a}^{a+b} \frac{e^{-u} + \frac{\operatorname{erfc}\sqrt u}{\sqrt u}}{2u}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u-a}}$$
Where we have simply let $a=r^2$ and $b=H^2$

---

We now assume that $b \gg a$, and notice that our integral decays extremely quickly. We can thus estimate this well as 
$$\int_a^{\infty} \frac{e^{-u} + \frac{\operatorname{erfc}\sqrt u}{\sqrt u}}{2u\sqrt{u-a}}du \;\stackrel{\text{Mathematica}}{=}\; \frac{\left(\pi- 2\pi^{1/2}\right)\operatorname{erfc}\left(a^{1/2}\right)}{2a^{1/2}}+\frac{e^{-a}}{a}$$